# Проблемы с диалоговым окном открытия файлов: Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Решил изучить диалоговые окна C# Windows Forms. Но столкнулся с одной неприятной проблемой.
Так вот. при запуске программы и нажатия на кнопку, вызывающую диалоговое окно, программа выдает ошибку
"экземпляра COM-компонента с CLSID {DC1C5A9C-E88A-4DDE-A5A1-60F82A20AEF7} при помощи интерфейса IClassFactory завершилось со сбоем из-за следующей ошибки: 80040111 Требуемый класс отсутствует в ClassFactory (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80040111 (CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE))."

вот, собственно, код:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
        richTextBox1.LoadFile(openFileDialog1.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
   }
}
```

P. S. в чем проблема? Получится ее как-нибудь исправить?

P. P. S. Заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: Не воспроизводиться. Единственное предположение, что Вы пытаетесь загрузить в richTextBox не текстовый файл с расширением txt, а что-то другое.

Comment: А сама панель Open/Save на компьютере работает? И вероятно, может берется длл х86 или 64, а приложение работает в обратном формате. Или выбранная версия .Нет ниже 4.0